# How to find value of RPC url in Jira Application for jenkins extension

Tags: jenkins, jira, integration

How to find value of RPC url in Jira Application for jenkins extension

Images included below show the RPC url field in extension.

I have local Jenkins running and Jira account on cloud.

[image: jenkins with jira extension added]
[image: jenkin extension setup in jira]

Answer (score 1):

Hope it helps you someone searcing for the RPC URL that JIRA requests.

For example, if your Jenkins installation sits at `http://somegoodname.com/`, visiting `http://somegoodname.com/api/` will show just the top-level API features available.

Select the format of data you want , and copy the link from address bar, that's your RPC.

in my case I selected JSON API and my RPC was

```
http://myjenkinssite/api/json?pretty=true
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the JIRA PLUGIN installed in jenkins if not get it and set it up

[image]

For more information https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JIRA+Plugin

Comment: I have Jira plugin setup and have done above, my question is on the Jira side, what url value to put there for Jenkin plugin in Jira cloud, which can be seen in picture attached in my original question

Comment: On JIRA side, there is no action necessary as the REST API is enabled by default. read the url which I have attached

Comment: But i am not using local jira, i am using the jira account on cloud, what will be url in that case, i have added the url as suggested by you, but how will the ticket code appear on every build? which tickets are covered by that build and how will jira come to know about the changes, the jenkins extension in jira allows to see build updates on jira side. I need to see changes both on jira and jenkins side

Comment: your gonna have to open the port of Jenkins to Jira  ...https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/jenkins-integrate-with-jira/qaq-p/427232 ... talks about the same issue...The reason Jenkins can talk to Jira is like you said its on the cloud, but Jira cannot find Jenkins cause it's running on you localhost(locally).... so you have to expose your port to the internet

Comment: @yashashreemehta  if this helped you in solving your issue please select it as the correct answer so that others, who face this issue will know what needs to be done